# Zend Framework 2 with cakephp 2.3

Tags: cakephp, zend-framework2, cakephp-2.0

I am building an application in cakePHP and wanted to use Zend Framework 2 with it. 2 compoments which I specifically want to use are captcha and lucene (I know it is maintained separately)

I have added the ZF2 library folder in app/vendor.

I tried using Zend classes using the two methods I found on various site.

[Method 1](http://britg.com/2008/07/07/using-the-zend-framework-in-cakephp/)

Added line to my controller Method

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Captcha_Figlet', true, false, 'Zend/Captcha/Figlet.php');
```

which gave me an error like

```
Error: Class 'Zend\Captcha\AbstractWord' not found
```

and I proceed to add all missing classes.

```
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Captcha', true, false, 'Zend/Captcha.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Validator_ValidatorInterface', true, false, 'Zend/Validator/ValidatorInterface.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Validator_Translator_TranslatorAwareInterface', true, false, 'Zend/Validator/Translator/TranslatorAwareInterface.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Validator_AbstractValidator', true, false, 'Zend/Validator/AbstractValidator.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Stdlib_ArrayObject_PhpReferenceCompatibility', true, false, 'Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject/PhpReferenceCompatibility.php');

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.4', 'lt')) {
  class_alias('Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject/PhpLegacyCompatibility', 'Zend/Stdlib/AbstractArrayObject');
} else {
  class_alias('Zend_Stdlib_ArrayObject_PhpReferenceCompatibility', 'Zend/Stdlib/AbstractArrayObject');
}

App::import('Vendor', 'Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject\PhpLegacyCompatibility', true, false, 'Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject/PhpLegacyCompatibility.php');

App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Stdlib_AbstractArrayObject',true,false,'Zend/Stdlib/AbstractArrayObject.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Stdlib_ArrayObject', true, false, 'Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend\Session\Container\PhpLegacyCompatibility', true, false, 'Zend/Session/Container/PhpLegacyCompatibility.php');

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.4', 'lt')) {
  class_alias('Zend\Session\AbstractContainer', 'Zend\Session\AbstractBaseContainer');
} else {
  class_alias('Zend\Session\Container\PhpReferenceCompatibility', 'Zend\Session\AbstractBaseContainer');
}

App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Session_Container', true, false, 'Zend/Session/Container.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Captcha_Exception_ExceptionInterface', true, false, 'Zend/Captcha/Exception/ExceptionInterface.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Captcha_Exception_InvalidArgumentException', true, false, 'Zend/Captcha/Exception/InvalidArgumentException.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Captcha_AdapterInterface', true, false, 'Zend/Captcha/AdapterInterface.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Captcha_AbstractAdapter', true, false, 'Zend/Captcha/AbstractAdapter.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Captcha_AbstractWord', true, false, 'Zend/Captcha/AbstractWord.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Text_Figlet_Figlet', true, false,'Zend/Text/Figlet/Figlet.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Math_Rand', true, false, 'Zend/Math/Rand.php');
App::import('Vendor', 'Zend_Captcha_Figlet', true, false, 'Zend/Captcha/Figlet.php');
```

.. until I was stuck here:

Error `Class 'Zend/Stdlib/ArrayObject/PhpReferenceCompatibility' not found` for line `class_alias('Zend_Stdlib_ArrayObject_PhpReferenceCompatibility', 'Zend/Stdlib/AbstractArrayObject');`

where  `class_alias('Zend_Stdlib_ArrayObject_PhpReferenceCompatibility', 'Zend/Stdlib/AbstractArrayObject');` is used to solve this '`Error: Class 'Zend\Session\AbstractBaseContainer' not found` '

Method 2 - Sorry could not find the link

Create a component and add methods

```
public function initialize(){
    $include = get_include_path();
    $include.= PATH_SEPARATOR. APP . 'vendors' . DS;
    $successful = set_include_path($include);

    if (!$successful) {
        throw new Exception('ZendComponent failed to set include path.', E_ERROR);
    }
    App::import('Vendor', 'Loader',true,false,'Zend/Loader.php');
}

public function loadClass($class, $dirs = null){
    Zend_Loader::loadClass($class, $dirs);
}
```

and in controller method call
    $this->Zend->loadClass('Captcha');

after declaring the component.

But it exits after giving an error: `Error: Class 'Zend_Loader' not found`

Any help with either of the two codes appreciate or any pointers to latest documentation/blog.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is add ZF2 to your include path. You can do this in your index.php file using the following:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . 'Vendor' . DS . 'zf2' . DS . 'library');
```

For me, I had the framework inside Vendor/zf2/library.

Then you'll need to register the autoloader. This can also be done inside your index.php (although I'm not sure yet about the performance hit, if any).

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
$f = stream_resolve_include_path(str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php');
if ($f !== false) {
    return include $f;
}
return false;
});
```

My goal was to override the cache library and use Zend Cache instead. I placed the ZendCacheEngine.php file inside Lib/Cache/Engine/ for that purpose and loaded the appropriate Zend class for that.

The final code looked something like this:

```
<?php
use Zend\Cache\StorageFactory;

class ZendCacheEngine extends CacheEngine {

    public function init($settings = array()) {
        $cache = StorageFactory::adapterFactory('apc', array('ttl' => 3600));
        $plugin = StorageFactory::pluginFactory('exception_handler', array('throw_exceptions' => false, ));
        $cache -> addPlugin($plugin);

        //This is just an example, the remainder of your code will go here..
    }
}
```

This worked for me.

I hope this helps.